# Изменить текст кнопки Add to cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вставил такой код на странице продукта чтобы появилась кнопка Add to cart:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

Как мне изменить текст этой кнопки? 
Вот этот:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {

return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

и этот код:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {

return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

не помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте фильтры:

`woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text` - для текста на странице товара
`woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` - для текста на странице категории

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text( $text, $instance ) {
    // Измените значение текста $text на кнопке
    return $text;
};

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```

Этот код надо добавить в functions.php вашей темы.

Comment: к сожалению это не дало никаких результатов.

Comment: у меня страница товара не стандартная, а кастомная, может из-за этого не работают эти фильтры?

Comment: ну а как вы выводите кнопку на своей странице?

Comment: я-то проверил на боевом сайте - все работает

Comment: я вывожу через do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

Comment: Должно работать. Эта акция подключает /loop/add-to-cart.php, там вызывается $product->add_to_cart_text(), в котором и вызываются указанные мной фильтры. Куда вы вставили тот кусок кода, что я дал в ответе?

Comment: в самом низу того файла, где и кнопка

Comment: А надо в function.php вашей темы. Я забыл написать в ответе, думал, это очевидно.

Comment: к сожалению это ничего не изменило

Comment: Давайте полную информацию о теме, плагинах, приведите полный код файла, где вы вызываете кнопку и его путь.